# On Netlify, how do I redirect a URL wildcard to that parent directory?

Tags: redirects, url, netlify, too-many-redirects

I have URLs I want to redirect to their parent folder/directory:

- `/hats-category/hats1`
- `/hats-category/hats2`
- `/hats-category/cool-hats`

Rule looks like this: `/hats-category/* /hats-category`

So I can redirect this way:

- `/hats-category/hats1 -> /hats-category`
- `/hats-category/hats2 -> /hats-category`
- `/hats-category/cool-hats -> /hats-category`

It looks like this leads to a redirect loop. How do I do this?